# How to write a recursive function that takes a list and return the same list without vowels?

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

I am supposed to write a recursive function that takes a list of strings or a list of lists of strings and return the list without vowels, if found. Here is my attempt to solve it:

```
def noVow(seq):
    keys = ['a','i','e','o','u','u']
    if not seq or not isinstance(seq, list) :
        return 
    else:
        if seq[0]  in keys:
            del seq[0]
            return (noVow(seq[0:]))
        else:
            return (noVow(seq[1:]))


li = ["b", "c", "d","a"]
print (noVow(li))
```

I am aware that the bug lies in my base case however I can't come up with the right base case.

Note that the recursive function has to be written in pure functional programming i.e. side effects are not allowed.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have the letter u twice?

Comment: @Hoopdady you're right, very unrelated!

Comment: Wouldn't `del seq[0]` be considered a *side effect* that negates pure functional programming which avoids mutable data?  Just trying to understand if your requirements are at cross purposes with one another.

Comment: @cdlane I am not sure actually, im more of an imperative programming-programmer and i am new to the functional programming concepts as whole. So yeah you might be right. since it produces side effects it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def no_vowel(seq):
    if not isinstance(seq, list):
        raise ValueError('Expected list, got {}'.format(type(seq)))
    if not seq:
        return []
    head, *tail = seq
    if isinstance(head, list):
        return [[no_vowel(head)]] + no_vowel(tail)
    else:
        if head in 'aeiou':
            return no_vowel(tail)
        else:
            return [head] + novowel(tail)
```

The cool unpacking of the list is a Python 3 feature, and is very similar to functional programmings pattern matching.

Comment: You have a typo `novowel` in the last line that should be `no_vowel`

Comment: Just to categorize, not criticise: of the two salient criteria of "a list of strings or a list of lists of strings" and "return the same list", yours nicely handles the list of lists situation but doesn't return the same list but a copy.

Comment: Wouldn't modifying the list in place constitute a side effect?

Comment: I agree and I address this issue in a comment on the OP's problem text and in the text of my own answer.  He's asking for contradictory things which can't all be satisfied.  But which criteria you choose to ignore, even with the best of reasons, probably should be documented in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> return the **same** list without vowels

Eh, you're *slicing* the original list in the recursive calls, so you have a **copy** not the same list.

More so, your code actually works, but since you're passing a *slice* of the list, the vowel items in the slice (not the original list) are deleted and the original remains unchanged.

You can instead use a *non-slicing* variant that moves from *start* to *end* indices of the original list:

```
def no_vow(seq, index=0):
    keys = ['a','i','e','o','u']
    if not seq or not isinstance(seq, list) or index >= len(seq):
        return 
    else:
        if seq[index] in keys:
            del seq[index]
            return no_vow(seq, index)
        else:
            return no_vow(seq, index+1)
```

Finally, if you're going to print your result, you shouldn't print the output of the function call (which will be `None`) but the list.

---

**Trial**:

```
li = ["b", "c", "e", "d", "a"]

no_vow(li) # list is modified in-place
print(li)
# ["b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: Just to categorize, not criticise: of the two salient criteria of "a list of strings or a list of lists of strings" and "return the same list", yours nicely returns the same list but doesn't handle the list of lists situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your base case returns a None. So whenever you passes the empty list the None is sent up the stack of recursive calls.

Moreover you are not storing the characters which are not vowels, so your else case is wrong.

What you can have is something like this:

```
>>> def noVow(seq):
...     keys = ['a','i','e','o','u','u']
...     if not seq or not isinstance(seq, list) :
...         return []
...     else:
...         if seq[0] in keys:
...             return noVow(seq[1:])
...         else:
...             return [seq[0]] + noVow(seq[1:])
```

Also `seq[0:]` is equivalent to `seq`.

Comment: *return the same list without vowels*. If you're slicing, you won't have the same list. And you'll be better off with a comprehension

Comment: Yup, missed the same list part.

Comment: Just to categorize, not criticise: of the two salient criteria of "a list of strings or a list of lists of strings" and "return the same list", yours doesn't handle either situation.

Answer (score 1):

To work for a list of lists containing string and a flat list of strings, you need to iterate over the sequence and then check the type:

```
def noVow(seq):
    vowels = {'a', 'i', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'u'}
    for ele in seq:
        if isinstance(ele, list):
            # a list so recursively process
            yield [s for s in noVow(ele)]
        # else it has to be a string so just see if it is not a vowel
        elif ele not in vowels:
            yield ele
```

You use it like:

```
In [39]: li
Out[39]: [['b', 'c'], ['d', 'a']]

In [40]: li[:] = noVow(li)

In [41]: print(li)
[['b', 'c'], ['d']]

In [42]: li = ["a","b","c","e"]

In [43]: li[:] = noVow(li)

In [44]: print(li)
['b', 'c']
In [10]: li = [["b", "c"], ["d", ["a"]]]
In [11]: li[:] = noVow(li)   
In [12]: li
Out[12]: [['b', 'c'], ['d', []]] # works for nested lists
```

If you wanted a flat list of all non-vowels and you can use python3, you can use *yield from*:

```
def noVow(seq):
    vowels = {'a', 'i', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'u'}
    for ele in seq:
        if isinstance(seq, list):
            yield from noVow(ele)
        elif ele not in vowels:
            yield ele
```

You use it the same way:

```
In [2]: li = [["b", "c"], ["d", "a"]]

In [3]: li[:] = noVow(li)

In [4]: li
Out[4]: ['b', 'c', 'd']

In [5]: li = ["a","b","c","e"]

In [6]: li[:] = noVow(li)

In [7]: li
Out[7]: ['b', 'c']
```

You can do the same with python2, you just need another loop

Comment: Just to categorize, not criticise: of the two salient criteria of "a list of strings or a list of lists of strings" and "return the same list", yours nicely handles both situations but only if you use the external assist of `li[:] = noVow(li)`

Comment: @cdlane, it mutates the original list and does at it lot more efficiently than deleting objects at random indexes. If i asked somebody to write a recursive function to operate on an arbitrary I would be a lot happier to see this than what else I have seen here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solution correctly implements both of the criteria "a list of strings or a list of lists of strings" and "return the same list" without any external assistance:

```
def noVowels(sequence, index=0):
    if not (sequence and type(sequence) is list and index < len(sequence)):
        return 

    vowels = {'a','i','e','o','u'}

    if type(sequence[index]) is list:
        noVowels(sequence[index])
    elif sequence[index] in vowels:
        del sequence[index]
        index -= 1

    noVowels(sequence, index + 1)

    return sequence
```

**TEST**

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', ['l', 'm', ['n', 'o', 'p'], 'q'], 'r', 's', 't', 'u']

print(array)
print(id(array))
print(id(array[0]))

result = noVowels(array)

print(result)
print(id(result))
print(id(result[0]))
```

**RESULT**

```
> python3 test.py
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', ['l', 'm', ['n', 'o', 'p'], 'q'], 'r', 's', 't', 'u']
4315447624
4315344520
[['b', 'c', 'd'], 'f', 'g', 'h', ['l', 'm', ['n', 'p'], 'q'], 'r', 's', 't']
4315447624
4315344520
>
```

Note that the same list, and inner lists, are left intact based on their id not changing.  And it handles a list of lists of lists.

I don't believe it's functional program because it works by side-effect but that contradiction is inherent in the OP's problem description.